# What kind of files I can use in GitHub Pages?

Tags: github-pages

I put yaml file on GitHub Pages, but I don't find that yaml file. I'll change file's extension (to txt), and I want to know what kind of files I can use? Any white list or document exist?

This is my trial and errors.

OK

- txt - http://tachikoma.io/i18n-step.txt
- html - http://tachikoma.io/index.html
- js - http://tachikoma.io/js/init.js
- css - http://tachikoma.io/css/prism.css
- json - http://tachikoma.io/locales/en/translation.json

NG(404)

- yml - http://tachikoma.io/example/bundler/.tachikoma.yml
- pot - http://tachikoma.io/_build/translation.pot

repository: https://github.com/tachikomaio/maguro.tachikoma.io

Edited: 2014-11-12
GitHub pages does not show a file which name starts with period e.g. `.example.yml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that GH pages tries to manage your site as a [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) site. Then ignoring some file name patterns.

If you want all your files to be copied just add an empty file named `.nojekyll` at the root of your site.

Comment: Great! I put `.nojekyll` and I can access both `.foo.yml` and `_build/foo.txt`. Thanks!

Comment: [Bypassing Jekyll on GitHub Pages](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages)